# is it necessary to have relationship between all entities in database

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

**Entity-Relationship** is confusing me. In some examples I couldn't find relationship between some entities, in other words I can't track information between them.

My question is

**"Is it necessary to have relationship between all entities in database. In other words, is it ok to have diagram without relationship, whether there is no relation, whether for simplicity"**

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe duplicate question. I found this question in http://dba.stackexchange.com/. [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-it-ok-to-have-an-entity-in-an-er-diagram-without-a-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Logically, entities are implicitly related by attributes having the same domain, and a database can be understood as a set of related data.  Thus, on the logical level, I believe that all entities in a database must necessarily be related.

On an ER diagram, however, the absence of relationship lines make it difficult to determine the foreign key domains, cardinality and constraints.  It's bad enough that most ER diagrams show physical types and not domains, and that most are poorly normalized.  Without any hint of dependencies, all we have is a visual table dump.

Where there is no direct relationship between two entities, no indication is required.  It's fine to show subsets of a schema in a diagram, to focus on particular aspects, as long as the missing information is indicated elsewhere.  Leaving out important and necessary information is not acceptable, though.